# Generic Descriptor Matcher function OPENCV

Tags: opencv

I would like to have a simple question for you but it was too hard to get for me so far. 
My question is:

There is a function in opencv svn called GenericDescriptorMatcher();

```
Ptr<GenericDescriptorMatcher> gdm = new VectorDescriptorMatcher( descriptorExtractor, descriptorMatcher );
```

I want to get an explanation about it but in a simple way, What it should be the

> descriptorExtractor

and What it should be

> descriptorMatcher

For God sake, for many days i'm working on this function and still don't know how to use it, so please if you have an experience with it, try to explain it in very simple way.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example

```
// Detect features
Ptr<FeatureDetector>     detector = new SurfFeatureDetector(400);
vector<KeyPoint> features;
detector->detect(image,   features); 

// Extract features
Mat descriptors;
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = new SurfDescriptorExtractor();
extractor->compute(image,     features, descriptors);

// Matcher of features
Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = new BruteForceMatcher<L2<float>>();

// Now you can match the features using matcher or use gdm
Ptr<GenericDescriptorMatcher> gdm = new VectorDescriptorMatcher( extractor, matcher);
```

Comment: Of course in order to perform image matching you are not obligated to use generic descriptor class. If you need help with image matching I can supply an example

Comment: Thank you Dani, but that's didn't work with me at all. I tried that but nothing working... I need this gdm value in order to evaluate the descriptor.. But if you have an example that you have used yourself, I would be so appreciated if you supply it.

Comment: Another question Dani, by using this function 
double match(const vector<KeyPoint>& /*kpts_train*/, const vector<KeyPoint>& /*kpts_query*/, DescriptorMatcher& matcher,
            const Mat& train, const Mat& query, vector<DMatch>& matches)


I wanted to draw the matches, so I need the matches, which I used this function but I got errors when I use it, do you have any idea 

double pop_time = match(keypoints1, keypoints2, matcher, descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);

Comment: Hei Mario, Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542339/calculate-offset-skew-rotation-of-similar-images-in-c/6545111#6545111,  I supplied full code of image matching example also with displaying matches for debug

Comment: Hi Dani, can I ask you why you use Bruteforce L2 not for example Haming, it is faster or just you used to use it? Thanks

Comment: Hei, no specific reason. Just for this example